# ReST API return 11 along with JSON success data

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I have written an API for updating the User information using the PUT method & here is the cURL code :

```
    $postData = http_build_query($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrl);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response  = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
```

Here $data is the Associative array (key=>value pair). After the request is done in the API end. I'm getting the response as :

11{"Status":200,"Response":"Success","ResponseData":"User Information updated successfully"}

Here, in the response. I'm not able to figure out why that integer value 11 is coming. Please do provide the reason & how to fix it.

thanks in advance,
Srinivasu....

Comment: If the API code is yours, as I understand it, then it is likely a forgotten `echo` statement in your code. Edit: looks like @a-p got there first ;)

Answer (score 0):

In that API function `11` is attaching, means there should be some `echo` before you are sending proper response. So, please go through your code and comment extra `echo` that will solve your Problem.

**EDIT**

This `11` may be before you are actually sending/returning response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cafonso & A.P for your answer. I have checked my Query for the echo statement & found one of the echo which is generating the 11 integer value..

Thanks for the solution..